# Sublime Text 3 Keeps Trying "Caching Information" in the status bar

Tags: text-editors, sublime-text-2, packages, sublime-text-3

I have a sublime text 3. and It keeps me showing "Caching Information" in the status bar, for the line I am editing. It seems it is trying to do something and have not been able to finish. Anybody has seen this issue?

My Package control settings are also gone. Now with Ctrl+Shift+p, I do not get any package control options like add/remove etc.

[image]

Comment: do you see any messages when you open the console?

Comment: No. Nothing. This is what the console has..`EasyDiff: svn not found or is not working!
EasyDiff: git 1.9.4.msysgit.0
EasyDiff: hg not found or is not working!
reloading Packages/User/SublimeServer.sublime-settings
>>> 
>>> `